# Opening a href link in Selenium Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to click on the following a href link in selenium. I have tried using xpath and `By.linkText()` and `By.cssSelectort()` but I have not be able to locate the element. Any help is much appreciated

```
driver.findElement(By.linkText("CCC_PH3_Sandbox_Keybridge: CCC PH3 Sandbox Keybridge")).click();
```

and `By.xpath()` but its unable to locate the element

```
WebElement course = driver.findElementByXPath("html/body/table/tbody/tr/td/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr/td[3]/a/span[1]");
course.click();
```

**css locator :**

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[href*='/webapps/portal']")).click();
```

Here is the **html snippet:**

```
<img width="12" height="12" src="/images/ci/icons/bookopen_li.gif" alt="">
<a target="_top" href=" /webapps/portal/frameset.jsp?tab_tab_group_id=_2_1&url=%2Fwebapps%2Fblackboard%2Fexecute%2Flauncher%3Ftype%3DCourse%26id%3D_2135_1%26url%3D">CCC_PH3_Sandbox_Keybridge: CCC PH3 Sandbox Keybridge</a>
```

Comment: Which exception you are getting ? Just check whether the link is in frame or now.

Comment: Please check whether the element is visible or not

Comment: what kind of error you are getting or is there any frame as its root?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Timed out after 10 seconds waiting for element to be clickable: By.partialLinkText: CCC_PH3_Sandbox_Keybridge

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `By.partialLinkText()` as below :-

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.partialLinkText("CCC_PH3_Sandbox_Keybridge"))).click();
```

**Edited**:- As you have mentioned this element is inside two iframes with id `navFrame` and `contentFrame`, you need to switch that iframes one by one before finding element as :-

```
driver.switchTo().frame("navFrame");
driver.switchTo().frame("contentFrame");

//Now find desire element 
new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.partialLinkText("CCC_PH3_Sandbox_Keybridge"))).click();

//After doing all stuff inside iframe switch back to default content 
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

Comment: Still timing out waiting for element to be clickable even though i see the element link and its clickable

Comment: Did you look for frame or iframe?? May be this element is inside frame or iframe.. if it is you need to switch that frame before finding this link..verify it

Comment: it has these two so it does appear to be in an iframe.     <iframe id="navFrame" frameborder="0" src="/webapps/portal/execute/topframe?tab_tab_group_id=_10_1&frameSize=LARGE" title="Header" name="nav" style="height: 89px;">
<iframe id="contentFrame" frameborder="0" src="/webapps/portal/execute/tabs/tabAction?tab_tab_group_id=_10_1" title="Content" name="content" style="height: 551px;">

Comment: @ccook14 Ok if this element inside two iframes you need to switch both iframes one by one before finding element, try with updated answer and let me know..:)

Comment: @saurabh_Gaur This is what im getting from your code                     Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchFrameException: No frame element found by name or id contentFrame

Comment: So are you sure desired element inside two iframes or only any one iframe??

Comment: I believe only one. 'contentFrame' specifically is what its in. the 'navFrame' appears to be just for the toolbar at the top. I deleted nav frame out and it works! thank you so much

Comment: @ccook14 According to exception seems iframe with id `contentFrame` is not inside in iframe with id `navFrame`. Please verify it that actually element present in which iframe??

Comment: @ccook14 then just remove this line `driver.switchTo().frame("navFrame")` from provided code and try ..